# How to query ElasticSearch with a wildcard

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm performing the following query in ElasticSearch 7.5.2 and getting the expected results:

```
message:org.jooq.exception.TooManyRowsException
```

But if I try like this, I get no results (even though it looks like a broader query):

```
message:*TooManyRowsException
```

The mapping in this field is:

```
"messages": {
  "match": "*message",
  "match_mapping_type":"string",
  "mapping": {
    "type":"text",
    "analyzer":"custom_standard"
  }
}
```

So, I think I'm misunderstanding how wildcards work in ES. Does anyone know why `*` is not matching "any character" in text fields?

Thanks.

By the way, I've also tried these variations with no luck:

```
message:*.TooManyRowsException
message:"*TooManyRowsException"
message:(*TooManyRowsException)
message:TooManyRowsException
```

## Reproducible example

- ### Create the index

  ```html
  curl -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -XPUT localhost:9200/twitter
  {
      "settings": {
          "analysis": {
              "analyzer": {
                  "custom_standard": {
                      "type": "custom",
                      "tokenizer": "uax_url_email",
                      "filter": ["lowercase", "snowball", "stop"]
                  }
              },
              "normalizer": {
                  "custom_lowercase": {
                      "type": "custom",
                      "filter": ["lowercase"]
                  }
              }
          }
      },
      "mappings": {
          "dynamic_templates": [
              {
                  "messages": {
                      "match": "*message",
                      "match_mapping_type":"string",
                      "mapping": {
                          "type":"text",
                          "analyzer":"custom_standard"
                      }
                  }
              }
          ]
      }
  }
  ```
- ### Index a document

  ```html
  curl -s -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -XPOST localhost:9200/twitter/_doc
  {
     "message": "org.jooq.exception.TooManyRowsException"
  }
  ```
- ### Perform a search that yields results

  ```html
  curl -s -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -XGET localhost:9200/twitter/_search
  {
      "query": {
          "query_string": {
              "query": "message:org.jooq.exception.TooManyRowsException"
          }
      }
  }
  ```
- ### Perform a search that doesn't yield results

  ```html
  curl -s -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -XGET localhost:9200/twitter/_search
  {
      "query": {
          "query_string": {
              "query": "message:*TooManyRowsException"
          }
      }
  }
  ```

Comment: Could you please share the full query you are trying to run?

Comment: @KevinQuinzel Updated with that info

Comment: Hi,

Maybe use wildcard query instead.

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.x/query-dsl-wildcard-query.html

And can you put a document so we can try to reproduce your case, I'm confuse with message:?? is it your field name or the content of your field? Thanks.

Comment: @Gabriel "message" is the name of one of the fields in our documents. Our actual queries contain AND, OR, NOT. Do you know if it's possible to use a wildcard search against one field while using exact searches against another? for example, my full query is more similar to: "cust_id:xyz AND source:uvw AND message:TooManyRowsException". So we have been putting that whole string inside of the query_string. I'll update the question in a moment with sample documents.

Comment: @Gabriel Updated with a reproducible example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Ignore this, see edit 2**

I think you're indeed misunderstanding how wildcards work. Can you post your complete mapping by chance? I see you're using [dynamic mapping](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/dynamic-templates.html#dynamic-templates), however dynamic mapping is used to set the type of a field depending on a condition, and has nothing to do with search behaviour directly. So for example, your mapping would take all string fields whose name ends with message, and map them as text fields.

Whether that is what you want or not is hard to say, but if you're doing that specifically to allow wildcard search, you probably don't need any of that.

To perform a wildcard search, you really only need the `*` at the proper place in your query string.

```
{
    "query": {
        "query_string": {
            "query": "*.TooManyRowsException",
            "default_field" : "message",
            "allow_leading_wildcard": true
        }
    }
}
```

or

```
{
    "query": {
        "query_string": {
            "query": "*message:.TooManyRowsException",
            "allow_leading_wildcard": true
        }
    }
}
```

should match all exceptions that start with `message:` and end with `.TooManyRowsExceptions`. You may also want to set the `default_field` to `messages`. More info on that can be found [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html#query-string-wildcard). Additionaly, a query_string query does alot more than just allow for wildcard search. It analyses your query, and parses things like `AND` or `OR`. Like @Gabriel mentioned, if all you want is wildcard search, a [wildcard](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-wildcard-query.html) query could be a better option for you:

```
{
    "query": {
        "wildcard": {
            "message": {
                "value": "*.TooManyRowsException",
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Edit:** Changed query examples base on feedback

**Edit2:** Your query is indeed correct. The problem, it seems, is your custom analyzer. The query string matches on the analyzed field, and your uax_email_analyzer is based on the standard analyzer:

```
{
  "analyzer": "custom_standard",
  "text": "org.jooq.exception.TooManyRowsException"
}
```

returns

```
{
  "tokens" : [
    {
      "token" : "org.jooq.exception.toomanyrowsexcept",
      "start_offset" : 0,
      "end_offset" : 39,
      "type" : "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position" : 0
    }
  ]
}
```

Therefore, your inital query will not match, while

```
{
    "query": {
        "query_string": {
            "query": "message:*org.jooq.exception.toomanyrowsexcept"
        }
    }
}
```

actually returns a match. I would probably use a different analyzer for a field like an exception message, but alternatively you could also send your query text through the analyzer first.

Comment: About the mapping: yes, that's what we want (we map some as searchable text, some others as terms, IPs, etc.) I tried `"message:*.TooManyRowsException"` without success. Notice, in my case, `message` is the field name, not part of the exception that I want to match. I'll put together a sample document and update my answer in a bit.

Comment: Updated the question with a reproducible example

Comment: Even if you have the field leading your query, you might still need the `allow_leading_wildcard` setting, see the updated query example.

Comment: Even with `allow_leading_wildcard` I don't get results. I noticed in [the docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html) that `allow_leading_wildcard` defaults to true anyways.

Comment: You're right, I misremembered that. Either way, I think I figured out your issue, see edit 2.

Comment: I used the [analyze API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-analyze.html). I use kibana, but with curl it should proably by something like `curl -s -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -XGET localhost:9200/twitter/_analyze`, followed by the above json

Comment: @MondKin Out of curiosity, did you manage to solve your issue with that?

Comment: Indeed, removing the custom analyzer allows me to query with something like `message:*.TooManyRowsException`. We'll need to rethink which analyzer we use where. Thanks for you help!